# How can I make my Zsh theme ("fade") look good in urxvt?

Tags: terminal, zsh, colors, terminal-emulator, rxvt

I am using Arch Linux and I don't have any preference for a terminal emulator yet.

Since `rxvt-unicode` seems to be the most popular one, I thought I'd try that first. I'm configuring it now using `.Xresources`, but I wonder how I could make my `zsh` theme look better. I use the `droid sans mono regular` font at size 10 and with anti-aliasing:

[image: Zsh fade theme in Urxvt]

As you can see, the green block characters are off and look like they're filled with little "dots".

Here is what it looks like in Gnome Terminal:

[image: Zsh fade theme in Gnome Terminal]

I know how to make the colors match and I know how to fix the letter width as well, but I don't know how I can make the prompt look good (the smooth gradient).

In Konsole for example, it looks wrong too.

Is this related to "true colors" (32-bit) and the lack of support for it in most terminals?

Any fix + explanation about what is involved here would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you expect the gradient to look like? If it's only 4 glyphs on either side, then wouldn't it have to be a visibly discrete gradient? (FWIW Konsole does support [truecolour](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728).)

Comment: @Sparhawk look at the screenshot from gnome terminal, it looks smooth on there. The block characters are completely "filled" and they have different brightness levels.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I thought "smooth gradient" referred to the number of discrete colours or steps. I can't answer the question regarding `rxvt-unicode`, but in my experience it's a fairly simple emulator, and you may not be able to configure this. I guess we're getting a little off topic, but is there anything wrong with using Gnome Terminal? (FWIW, I use Terminator.)

Comment: @Sparhawk no there is nothing wrong with another terminal, like I said I'm fairly new to the Linux world and don't have a preference yet. But I _am_ a power user and developer, and I just prefer lightweight and configurable/extensible software. Still I wonder what gnome terminal does that others don't to make those Zsh themes look good. Like I said, it looks wrong in Konsole too.

Comment: I suppose I'm suggesting that perhaps instead of spending a lot of time troubleshooting `rxvt-unicode`, which is not very configurable/extensible, you might like to try others. In my experience (with a four-year-old laptop), I've never noticed any performance difference between terminal emulators.

Comment: @Sparhawk you're right, another terminal emulator looks like the best option for me. Terminator looks promising!